# Want to separate the positive and negitive words in wordcloud using Jupitor notbook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sentiment-analysis, word-cloud, code-separation

I am doing sentiment analysis i already genrate wordcloud as a whole but stuck in the separation of positive and negitive words in wordcloud using jupitor notebook

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: # find term using wordcloud
allwords = ''.join([review for review in df_sv['review']])
wordCloud = WordCloud(width=500, height=300,random_state=21, max_font_size=119, background_color='white').generate(allwords)
plt.imshow(wordCloud, interpolation = "bilinear")
plt.axis('off')
plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

The wordcloud is just another way of displaying the frequency of your words. It has nothing to do with the sentiment of such words. You will have to perform sentiment analysis on the "words, sentences or document as a whole". The level of granularity depends on the purpose of the task at hand.

Things you may want to consider :

- text preprocessing - removing stop words
- you will need to categorize or classify the text into one specific sentiment polarity, **positive or negative (or neutral)**

etc etc

-